MediaRecorder API with MP4 in Chrome Requires Warm-Up for Proper Playback When Switching Streams
I want to implement a feature that captures a media stream from the user's webcam and records it using the Media Recorder API.
The key requirements of this feature are as follows:

To ensure browser compatibility, the MIME type must be "video/mp4" (as Chromium browsers now support MP4 recording with a recent update).
Even if the media stream changes during recording, the recording should continue uninterrupted.

However, as specified in Section 15.4 of https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/#dom-mediarecorder-start, the Media Recorder API is designed to stop recording if the stream is switched during recording.
So, while I was contemplating, I discovered a hack to work around it.
The idea is to create a local RTCPeerConnection for sending/receiving media streams and use the replaceTrack() method to switch media stream tracks.
I tried implementing this logic using React and TypeScript, and while it seems to work, there's a catch.
Specifically, it requires "WARMING UP" before recording. 
What I mean is that if you visit my project and run it, you'll notice that if you start recording immediately after the media stream is loaded into the video element, the recorded video doesn't play back properly like, this image.
However, if you load the media stream into the video element, wait for some time (about 10–15 seconds), and then start and stop recording, the recorded video plays back perfectly.
It seems like there's a race condition, but I couldn't identify it despite thoroughly reviewing the code.
Could I be missing something?
P.S. An interesting point is that if the MIME type is changed to video/webm, the "warming up" process is no longer needed.
Could it be an issue with the MP4 format?

Added on November 22, 2024, at 11:21 AM.
I have confirmed that turning off the hardware acceleration setting in the Chrome browser completely resolves the issue.
However, this does not seem to be a fundamental solution.
Guiding all users of my service to "Chrome - Settings - System - please turn off hardware acceleration" is a very inconvenient solution.
Please help...
